# If $S\subseteq A^*$ is separating, does $S$ also separate $M(A)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, multiplier-algebra

Let $A$ be a non-unital $C^*$-algebra. Let $S\subseteq A^*$ be a set of continuous functionals that separates the points of $A$. Every element $\omega \in A^*$ extends uniquely to a strictly continuous functional $\omega \in M(A)^*$, so we can ask: does $S$ also separate the points of $M(A)$? Concretely, if $m \in M(A)$ and $\omega(m)=0$ for all $\omega \in S$, do we have $m=0$?

In some cases, this is automatically true. For instance, if $AS \subseteq S$ or $SA\subseteq S$ this is easily seen to be true. However, it is not clear to me if this is true in general. My intuition tells me that the answer is "no" but I have trouble finding a concrete counterexample. It's not even clear to me what happens if $A= C_0(X)$ or $A=B_0(H)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, it's not true in general. If $A = c_0$ then the multiplier algebra is the same as the double dual, $l^\infty$. Then we want a linear subspace of $l^1$ which is weak* dense (so it separates $c_0$) but not norm dense (so it doesn't separate $l^\infty$). This can be achieved by taking any $\vec{a} \in l^\infty \setminus c_0$ and letting $S$ be its kernel in $l^1$. For instance, taking $\vec{a} = 1$, we get $S = \{\vec{b} \in l^1: \sum b_n = 0\}$. This separates $c_0$ but not $l^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe some short follow-up questions: What do you mean with the weak$^*$-topology on $l^1$? Does it come from the natural embedding $l^1 \hookrightarrow (l^\infty)^*$? Why is $S$ weak$^*$-dense in $l^1$?

Comment: $l^1$ as the dual of $c_0$. A codimension 1 subspace of $l^1$ is weak* closed iff it is the kernel of the map evaluating on some $\vec{a} \in c_0$; since our $\vec{a}\not\in c_0$ its kernel cannot be weak* closed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more thing: How are we sure that the elements $\ell^1 \subseteq (\ell^\infty)^*$ are continuous w.r.t. the strict topology on $\ell^\infty 
= M(c_0)$? Maybe the strict topology on $\ell^\infty$ admits a nice description relating it with some weak$^*$-topology (on bounded subsets)?

Comment: "Every element $\omega \in A^*$ extends uniquely to a strictly continuous functional $\omega \in M(A)^*$"

Comment: You start with functionals on $M(A)$ (where $A= c_0$), so how do we know that these come from strictly continuous functionals on $A=c_0$? It can happen that an element $\omega \in M(A)^*$ does not come from a strictly continuous functional on $A$ right? Do I miss something?

Comment: "You start with functionals on $M(A)$" --- look for the place in my answer where I said this, and realize that I didn't.

Comment: It seems that you're having difficulty with abstraction. Can you look at the specific example $S = \{\vec{b} \in l^1: \sum b_n = 0\}$ and verify directly that it separates $c_0$ but not $l^\infty$?

Comment: Alright, it becomes a little clearer to me: we have functionals in $\ell^1 = c_0^*$, so indeed we start with functionals on $c_0$. We can also view elements in $\ell^1$ as functionals on $\ell^\infty$, and I guess my question is: why are these strictly continuous (on bounded subsets). I think I can show this using a standard estimate. Would you agree that showing this strict continuity is necessary? Or does it somehow follow trivially? (sorry if I am overcomplicating this, really appreciate the help).

Comment: "Every element $\omega \in A^∗$ extends uniquely to a strictly continuous functional $\omega \in M(A)^*$"

Comment: I am quoting your own post.

Comment: Yes, I see that. My question is, if $\omega \in c_0^* = \ell^1$, can we say how the strict extension $\omega\in (\ell^\infty)^*$ looks like? I would suspect that if $\omega$ is given by $f \in \ell^1$, then $\omega(g) = \sum_n f(n)g(n)$ for $f\in \ell^\infty$. This is definitely a well-defined extension, but shouldn't we check this is a strictly continuous?

Comment: You need to check this yourself.

Comment: Yes, I can show this using a standard approximation argument. Just wanted to make sure that I actually had to check this! Thanks for all the help. Everything is clear now!